# Caching strategy suggestions needed

Tags: caching, memcached

We have a fantasy football application that uses memcached and the classic memcached-object-read-with-sql-server-fallback. This works fairly well, but recently I've been contemplating the overhead involved and whether or not this is the best approach.

Case in point - we need to generate a drop down list of the users teams, so we follow this pattern:

1. Get a list of the users teams from memcached
2. If not available get the list from SQL server and store in memcached.
3. Do a multiget to get the team objects.
4. Fallback to loading objects from sql store these.

This is all very well - each cached piece of data is relatively easily cached and invalidated, but there are two major downsides to this:

1) Because we are operating on objects we are incurring a rather large overhead - a single team occupies some hundred bytes in memcached and what we really just need for this case is a list of team names and ids - not all the other stuff in the team objects.

2) Due to the fallback to loading individual objects, the number of SQL queries generated on an empty cache or when the items expire can be massive:
   1 x Memcached multiget (which misses, which and causes)
   1 x SELECT ... FROM Team WHERE Id IN (...)
   20 x Store in memcached
So that's 21 network request just for this one query, and also the IN query is slower than a specific join.

Obviously we could just do a simple

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Teams WHERE UserId = XYZ
```

And cache that result, but this this would mean that this data would need to be specifically invalidated whenever the user creates a new team. In this case it might seem relatively simple , but we have many of these type of queries, and many of them operate on axes that are not easily invalidated (like a list of id and names of the teams that your friends have created in a specific game).

Sooo.. My question is - do any of you have ideas for resolving the mentioned drawbacks, or should I just accept that there is an overhead and that cache misses are bad, live with it?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

First, cache what you need, maybe that two fields, not a complete record.

Second, cache what you need again, break the result set into records and cache them seperately

Answer (score 0):

### about caching:

You generally use caching to offload the slower disc-based storage, in this case mysql. The memory cache scales up rather easily, mysql scales less easy.

Given that, even if you double the cpu/netowork/memory usage of the cache and putting it all together again, it will still offload the db. Adding another nodejs instance or another memcached server is easy.

### back to your question

1. You say its a user's team, you could go and fetch it when the user logs-in, and keep it updated in cache while the user changes it throughout his session.
2. I presume the team member's names do not change, if so you can load all team members by id,name and store those in cache or even local on nodejs, use the same fallback strategy as you do now. Only step 1 and 2 and 4 will be left then.

personally i usually try to split the sql results into smaller ready-made pieces and cache those, and keep the cache updated as long as possible, untimately trying to use mysql only as storage and never read from it

usually you will run some logic on the returned rows form mysql anyways, theres no need to keep repeating that.